# How to open a link in new tab on right click

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the below code

```
<a href="/program/2" (click)="onSelect(2)" >{{"2"}}</a>
```

The problem with this solution is that when I click, the function works, but `href` also is activated.
What i want to do is that when i click the method is called and the href is not called.
When i tried right click and choose "open new Tab" then the href is activated, and the method isn't closed.

Usually, I could solve this problem by using `[routerLink]` as it allows me to open the function and it will also allow `new-tab` on right-click.

```
<a [routerLink]="onSelect(2)" >{{"2"}}</a>
```

But I can't use it as I have an exception here:

> parent(`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked`).

Is there any other solution that will allow me to call the function on click, and when I do right click it can go to the `href="/program/2"`.

**Note**: I want the `href` to go to a new page (when I right-click). When I click it should remain on the same page as I am calling the parent which later adds `/program/2` to the route.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very intuitive UX. Also, your post title doesn't reflect what's being asked in the post. Please revise.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers but what i need is that when i want to open to a new tab i will use href, And when i click the href will not be called. Cause right now it works but my component is reload twice when i click.

Comment: Basically if i click somehow i want that href be disable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

define target as _blank to  tag

```
<a href="" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer how to do it with a right-click.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a  [routerLink]="onSelect(2)" (contextMenu)="openExternal('/program/2')" >{{"2"}}</a>
```

and in your component add method:

```
openExternal(link) {
    window.open(link, "_blank")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a target to  element, like this

`<a  href="jsvascript:;" (click)="onSelect(2)" target="_blank">{{"2"}}</a>`

with: `target="_blank"` the link will open in new tab and with `href="javascript:;"` you avoid the href get activated on click.